# Haskell Using multiple functions in one function

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use multiple functions in my code but it's not really working. Is there any way to apply multiple functions in on function? I'm getting this error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `(Integer, Integer) -> String -> t'
                  with actual type `(Integer, Integer)'
    * The function `a' is applied to two arguments,
      but its type `(Integer, Integer)' has none
      In the expression: a b c
      In an equation for `event': event = a b c
    * Relevant bindings include
        event :: t (bound at E:\\ELTE\2019_1_Funkcprog\hf2.hs:28:10)
```

Code

```
type Event = ((Integer, Integer), (Integer, Integer), String)

shift :: (Integer, Integer) -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
shift (x, y) z = case y + z >= 60 of
    True -> ((div ((x*60 + y)  + z) 60) `mod` 24, mod ((x*60 + y)  + z) 60)
    False -> (x, y + z)


isEarlier :: (Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer) -> Bool
isEarlier (a, b) (c, d) = case a < c || a == c && b < d of
    True -> True
    False -> False 


first :: (a, b, c) -> a
first (x, _, _) = x
second :: (a, b, c) -> b
second (_, y, _) = y
third :: (a, b, c) -> c
third (_, _, z) = z


createEvent :: (Integer, Integer) ->  Integer -> String -> Event
createEvent x y z = event
   where a = first (x,y,z) 
         b = shift x y 
         c = third (x,y,z)
         event = a b c
```

Comment: `event = a b c` is short for `(a b) c`, it thus means `a` should be of type `tb -> tc -> td`, with `tb` and `tc` the types of `b` and `c` respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `event = a b c`, this means "*apply function `a` to two arguments, `b` and `c`*". That's how function application works in Haskell. Function, then space, then argument.

Because you wrote this, thinks Haskell, `a` must be a function. What type of function must it be? Well, look at types of `b` and `c`. Since `b :: (Integer, Integer)`, and `c :: String`, function `a` must be of type `(Integer, Integer) -> String -> something`

But wait! - thinks Haskell - Where did `a` even come from? Oh, it was returned from `first`, and the result of `first` must have the same type as its first tupled argument, and I'm passing `x` in that position, and `x :: (Integer, Integer)`, therefore `a` must also be of type `(Integer, Integer)`

Hmmm, - thinks Haskell, - on one hand I have determined that `a :: (Integer, Integer) -> String -> something`. On the other hand, I have determined that `a :: (Integer, Integer)`. DOES NOT COMPUTE!

And so Haskell complains: *Couldn't match expected type '(Integer, Integer) -> String -> t' with actual type '(Integer, Integer)'*

Lesson here: read and try to understand the error messages. In Haskell they are usually quite helpful.

---

From your definition of the type `Event`, I am *guessing* that what you actually meant to do is to create a triple of `a`, `b`, and `c`. If so, the correct syntax is this:

```
event = (a, b, c)
```